# Why additional memory allocation makes multithread Python application work few times faster?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing python module which one of the functions is to check multiple IP addresses if they're active and write this information to database. As those are I/O bound operations I decided to work on multiple threads:

- 20 threads for pinging host and checking if it's active (function `check_if_active`)
- 5 threads for updating data in database (function `check_if_active_callback`)

Program works as followed:

1. Main thread takes IPs from database and puts them to queue `pending_ip`
2. One of 20 threads takes record from `pending_ip` queue, pings host and puts answer to `done_ip` queue
3. One of 5 threads takes record from `done_ip` queue and does update in database if needed

What I've observed (during timing tests to get answer how many threads would suit the best in my situation) is that program works aprox. 7-8 times faster if in 5 loops I first declare and start 20+5 threads, delete those objects and then in 6th loop run the program, than if I run program without those additional 5 loops.

I suppose this could be somehow related to memory management. Not really sure though if deleting objects makes any sense in python. My questions are:

- why is that happening?
- how I can achieve this time boost without additional code (and additional memory allocation)?

Code:

```
import time, os
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
from readconfig import read_db_config
from mysql.connector import Error, MySQLConnection
pending_ip = Queue()
done_ip = Queue()

class Database:
    connection = MySQLConnection()
    def connect(self):
        db_config = read_db_config("mysql")
        try:
            self.connection = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
    def close_connection(self):
        if self.connection.is_connected() is True:
            self.connection.close()
    def query(self, sqlquery):
        if self.connection.is_connected() is False:
            self.connect()
        try:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sqlquery)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            return rows
    def update(self,sqlquery, var):
        if self.connection.is_connected() is False:
            self.connect()
        try:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sqlquery, var)
            self.connection.commit()
        except Error as e:
            self.connection.rollback()
            print(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()

db=Database()

def check_if_active(q):
    while True:
        host = q.get()
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 -W 2 %s > /dev/null 2>&1" % (host))
        if response == 0:
            ret = 1
        else:
            ret = 0
        done_ip.put((host, ret))
        q.task_done()


def check_if_active_callback(q, db2):
    while True:
        record = q.get()
        sql = "select active from table where address_ip='%s'" % record[0]
        rowIP = db2.query(sql)
        if(rowIP[0][0] != record[1]):
            sqlupdq = "update table set active=%s where address_ip=%s"
            updv = (record[1], record[0])
            db2.update(sqlupdq, updv)
        q.task_done()


def calculator():
    #some irrelevant code
    rows = db.query("select ip_address from table limit 1000")
    for row in rows:
        pending_ip.put(row[0])
    #some irrelevant code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_threads_pinger = 20
    num_threads_pinger_callback = 5
    db = Database()
    for i in range(6):
        db_pinger_callback =[]
        worker_p = []
        worker_cb = []
        #additional memory allocation here in 5 loops for 20 threads
        for z in range(num_threads_pinger):
            worker = Thread(target=check_if_active, args=(pending_ip))
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()
            worker_p.append(worker)
        #additional memory allocation here in 5 loops for 5 threads
        for z in range(num_threads_pinger_callback):
            db_pinger_callback.append(Database())
            worker = Thread(target=check_if_active_callback, args=(done_ip, db_pinger_callback[z]))
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()
            worker_cb.append(worker)

        if i == 5:
            start_time = time.time()
            calculator()
            pending_ip.join()
            done_ip.join()
            print "%s sec" % (time.time() - start_time)

        #freeing (?) that additional memory
        for z in range(num_threads_pinger - 1, 0, -1):
            del worker_p[z]
        #freeing (?) that additional memory
        for z in range(num_threads_pinger_callback - 1, 0, -1):
            db_pinger_callback[z].close_connection()
            del db_pinger_callback[z]
            del worker_cb[z]

        db.close_connection()
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to give you an exact explanation it would help to know what version of Python you're using.

For instance if you're using PyPy then what you've observed is the JIT kicking in after you call your loop 5 times and it just returns a pre-calculated answer. If you're using a standard version of Python then this speed up is due to the interpreter using the compiled byte code from the `.pyc` files.

How it works is basically Python will first create an in memory representation of your code and run it from there. During repeated calls the interpreter will convert some of the more often used code into byte code and store it on disk in `.pyc` files (this is python byte code similar to java byte code not to be confused with native machine code). Every time you call the same function the interpreter will go to your `.pyc` files and execute the corresponding byte code this makes the execution much faster as the code you're running is precompiled compared to when you call the function once and python has to parse and interpret your code.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. I think this doesn't explain the problem. Those two functions could be converted to byte code, but during 5 loops they're not fully executed any single time (queue is empty). Another thing is that most of the time take I/O bound operations which for sure are not converted into anything.

Comment: And to be clear. We're talking about improvement from ~150 seconds to ~20seconds